# How Can I Scroll two UILabels and a UIWebView with the same scroll IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiscrollview

I would like to group two UILabels and one UIWebView with just one scroll for this three components.

I don't know how I can do this ?

I tried with a UIScrollView in .XIB who include labels and UIWebView but it doesn't work.

If it possible I would like a graphic solution.

Comment: Easy solution is to add those as a childview of single scroll view but i have solution from code. I dont use nib or storyboard for such cases.

Comment: Okay, I prefer with the code then :) I tried with the code to create my UiScrollView and after add my three components and at the end I add my UiScrollView in my view but doesn't work too...
Do you have a other solution? @BishalGhimire

Answer (score 1):

The soultion is more complex then you actually think

1st add a scrollView

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView            * scrollView;
```

Then add it as subvew from View

```
self.scrollView                 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

But the most complex part is webview coz it has its own scroll part to fix that -

```
self.webViewNewsBody.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        self.webViewNewsBody.scrollView.bounces = NO;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.webViewNewsBody];
```

Yet you cant find the final ht of the web view hence wait till it loads its content

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
            CGRect frame;
            float webHt = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"] floatValue];
        // Finally set the total ht for the scroll view 
     self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, 300 + webHt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what component I create in graphic and what I create with a code? And if your solution works with the graphic how can I include component?

Comment: personally i never use graphical solution. this solution is has shown you how to add webview i think you just need to add UIlabels now. Its better to do such things from code once you get used to it. DO follow this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/55384/ios-7-best-practices-part-1

Answer (score 0):

At first make Outlets for you labels and webView

```
[UIView animateWIthDuration:0.2 animations:(^{
    CGFrame fr = self.labelFirst.frame;
    frame.origin.y += 50;
    self.labelFirst.frame = fr;
    fr = self.labelSecond.frame;
    fr.origin.y += 50;
    self.labelSecond.frame = fr;
    fr = self.webView.frame;
    fr.origin.y += 50;
    self.webView.frame = fr;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

make webView Scrollable no

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```